# Assertion fail message for string contains substring

Tags: java, string, junit, functional-testing, assertions

I have done a lot of functional testing on text outputs on text generating software lately, an find myself writing a lot of

```
assertTrue(actualString.contains(wantedString));
```

However, the message for when this fails is something non-descriptive like

```
Expected [true], but was [false]
```

An alternative is to include a custom fail message as

```
String failMsg = String.format("Wanted string to contain: %s, Actual string: %s", wantedString, actualString);
assertTrue(failMsg, actualString.contains(wantedString));
```

But it feels a bit tedious to do this manually all the time.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Personally I don't bother writing extra messages for the most part - tests rarely fail, and when they do, debug into them for more details :)

Comment: For unit tests - no, but these being functional (integration) tests, that might be running on an Jenkins server somewhere, the added level of detail is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use hamcrest Matcher `containsString()`

```
// Hamcrest assertion
assertThat(person.getName(), containsString("myName"));

// Error Message
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: a string containing "myName"
     got: "some other name"
```

You can optional add an even more detail error message.

```
// Hamcrest assertion with custom error message
assertThat("my error message", person.getName(), containsString("myName"));

// Error Message
java.lang.AssertionError: my error message
Expected: a string containing "myName"
     got: "some other name"
```