# How to assert elements contains text in Selenium using JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, assert

I have a page that I know contains a certain text at a certain xpath. In firefox I use the following code to assert that the text is present:

```
assertEquals("specific text", driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath)).getText());
```

I'm asserting step 2 in a form and confirming that a certain attachment has been added to the form.
However, when I use the same code in Chrome the displayed output is different but does contain the specific text. I get the following error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[]specific text> but was:<[C:\fakepath\]specific text>
```

Instead of asserting something is true (exactly what I'm looking for) I'd like to write something like:

```
assert**Contains**("specific text", driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath)).getText());
```

The code above does not work obviously but I can't find how to get this done.

Using Eclipse, Selenium WebDriver and Java

Comment: I believe this question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092219/assertcontains-on-strings-in-junit

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
String actualString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText();
assertTrue(actualString.contains("specific text"));
```

You can also use the following approach, using `assertEquals`:

```
String s = "PREFIXspecific text";
assertEquals("specific text", s.substring(s.length()-"specific text".length()));
```

to ignore the unwanted prefix from the string.

Comment: Thank you! I used the following and that worked fine:
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText().contains("specific text"));

Comment: You can optionally add a second parameter, with a custom error message for if it fails. For example: `assertTrue(s.contains("specific text"), "String did not contain the required text.");`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this code:

```
String actualString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(actualString.contains("specific text"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Two Methods assertEquals and assertTrue could be used.
Here is the usage

```
String actualString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText();

String expectedString = "ExpectedString";

assertTrue(actualString.contains(expectedString));
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but has anyone done the same thing in C#? I would love to see that code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly and `assert` however and other way is to use a `wait.until` and `ExpectedCondition`, then if condition is not satisfied the test will fail:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "xpath")
    private WebElement xpathElementToCheckText;
      
    public void checkElementText() {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // timeout in seconds
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(xpathElementToCheckText,"specific text"));
    }
```